# Reading from text file in Java

Tags: java, file

```
"a":"12345","b" : "2432334"
"a":"86543","b" : "4345534"
"a":"74564","b" : "4351234"
"a":"52454","b" : "6443534"
```

This is a `txt` file , I want to read the text file and print only numbers corresponding to "b" i.e `2432334,4345534,4351234,6443534`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

while ( (line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    linecount++;

    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    while (m.find()) {
        int start = m.start(0);
        int end = m.end(0);
        /*System.out.println("Word was found at position " + 
                       m.start() + " on line " + linecount);*/
        System.out.println(line.substring(start, end));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried already.

Comment: Welcome! Check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried? What isn't working? What have you read?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split` method to do that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.txt));
        while(in.ready()){
            String[] arr = in.readLine().split("\"");
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(arr[arr.length-1]));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work and in your inner while loop, you just need to get  `m.group(1)`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"b\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

while ( (line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    linecount++;

    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Here's the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yG6yL0/1) you can test it with.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like that also:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        String cutString ;
        File f = new File("D:\\test.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((cutString = br.readLine())!= null){

            String split1[] = cutString.split("b");

            String split2[]=split1[1].split(":");
            String split3[] = split2[1].split("\"");
            System.out.print(split3[1]);
            System.out.print(",");

        }


    }
```

Comment: With this I can read only one line data....Iteration should be done...I want to read each and every line ...Thanks in advance for your response...

Comment: no,you can read all line.plz test it.but i print all values in one line only.if you want to print all data by line by line,system.out.println(","); and tell me it is work or not after you test with my code.